# jQuery and reference to js and vsdoc.js files

Tags: jquery

Within vs.net I need to set references to both js and vsdoc.js files for jQuery.  Things work great if the script files are within the project HOWEVER I really want to reference a standard folder on our server i.e. http://www.domain.com/script/jQuery for the location of these files.  On our local workstation we have these files located in http://localhost/script/jQuery

How can I reference both consistent location as well as get the benefits of intellsense and F5 (development server) references working well?

thx

Answer (score 0):

If I undrestand your question well, then you could use relative address for your jQuery JS files.

So for linking to JS files just use "/script/jQuery/XXXX.JS" in your script tag instead of using http://localhost/script/jQuery/XXXX.JS or http://www.domain.com/script/jQuery/XXXX.JS !

Also if you want to have production-ready js file for jQuery (.min.js) you can link that but in your JS files add reference to VSDOC (Drag it and drop VSDOC file on top of your js code to add reference for it)

I hope this helps but if you mean something else, would you please explain more so we can help better :)